# AVAudioPlayer Doesn't play the songs inside the folders?

Tags: ios, avplayer, nsdocumentdirectory

I used this code to play songs it is not playing the songs inside the folders or folders of folders except the Documents directory.

```
NSString *songname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",songArray[songIndex]];
NSLog(@"songname:%@",songname);

NSString* saveFileName = songname;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
self.audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no Errors.Is there any way to search the files by name in document directory(folders of folders)??

Comment: Do you have this anywhere after that code? `[self.audioPlayer play]`?

Comment: Yes.I have it is playing the songs in the document directory but it is not playing the songs in nested folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"github.mp4"];
NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url1] ;
[self.avplayer play];
```