# Error when trying to use AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

The following code yields the following error. 
Not sure why?

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/abc.m4a",
                           [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                               error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player play];
```

---

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BasicArithmaticViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: needed framework:  /system/library/frameworks/avfoundation.framework

Comment: FYI - do not get the path using the code in your question. Use `NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"abc" withExtension:@"m4a"];`.

Comment: ok... well no errors... but no sound either

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17782212/2522603

Comment: this works "AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1005);"but still can't get AVAudioPlayer to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the framework for AVFoundation.